# is it possible to use a webpage to enter information into a terminal with php

Tags: php, html, javascript, forms

I was wondering if it is possible to enter information into a php exec using something like a text bar on a webpage, so when they enter a word and hit "continue" php takes that word and uses it in a command in the terminal of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, yes this is possible.

**Notes**

- Rather than parsing $argv and $argc, you would be parsing something like e.g. [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).
- You would need to have a web-based input (e.g. a web server on localhost with a basic [HTML form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)) and script that could be run by your web server as the target of that form (this would include the `exec()` command).
- You would almost certainly want to screen the input for malicious code.